# Bartle Real Analysis Theorem 8.2.3

Tags: real-analysis

[image]Need help understanding how the author combined the 3 inequalities towards the end of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is just coming from

$$\begin{aligned}
\left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - g(c) \right\vert &=\left\vert \left(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - \frac{f_K(x)-f_K(c)}{x-c}\right)+ \left( \frac{f_K(x)-f_K(c)}{x-c} - f^\prime_K(c)\right) + \left( f^\prime_K(c) - g(c)\right)\right\vert\\
&\le \left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - \frac{f_K(x)-f_K(c)}{x-c}\right\vert + \left\vert \frac{f_K(x)-f_K(c)}{x-c} - f^\prime_K(c)\right\vert + \left\vert f^\prime_K(c) - g(c)\right\vert
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The first term is less than epsilon, but what about the other two terms, how do we show they are less than epsilon?

Comment: I think we should use the derivative of fk at c, instead of difference quotient

Comment: @saluzulfi You're right. Answer updated.